# Ubuntu server 12.04 upgrade php version to 5.3.19

Tags: server, php

i am working on a ubuntu 12.04 server edition as a virtual machine. Basically, I want to upgrade the PHP version to the freshly released 5.3.19, but obviously I have absolutely no clue on how to do it.

Using apt-get install php5-cli etc. did not work, since it still gets me 5.3.19.

So, after having quite a look at google.com, i could not find anything helping me out. So I went to linuxquestions.org and asked ppl there, noone answered. So here are all my hopes, please help!!

If you have any explanations for me, please give them newbie-style. i am a newbie.

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: http://www.jeffmould.com/2013/10/06/upgrading-from-php-5-3-to-5-x-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to upgrade to the latest release versions upstream. There's a reason for sticking with the ones in the stable, `-updates` and `-security` software channels of the repositories.

The version 5.3.10 in Precise **is** updated for security fixes and bugs. See the [package changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4/changelog):

```
php5 (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4) precise-security; urgency=low

  * SECURITY UPDATE: [...]

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Tue, 11 Sep 2012 11:28:52 -0400
```

See als this question: ["Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: But what IF I do want to do this? Do you know the way to do it?

Comment: It's not that I want to know why not to do it, it is exactly how to do it, even if it is a bad idea.

Comment: One way, I totally *don't recommend* is building from upstream source. You can get PHP source from php.net and build it yourself. If you're a 'newbie' as you state yourself, this will be tough but you'll learn a lot. Be sure to understand the downsides of this: no easy uninstall, possibly overwrites files now managed by your package management, no automatic updates, etc.

Comment: Another way is finding a PPA providing you updated packages. Easier, better manageable, but totally not good production - as it's from an untrusted source.

Comment: The goal for me would then be building it by hand. Is there any link to any helping page that would help me building it?

Comment: @lukas What have you tried from the many results I find on Google using keywords "install php from source ubuntu"?

Comment: Ah, okay - I used the wrong keywords for search, eg. "compiling php" or something. "from source" helps a lot!